# Save as Draft functionality

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type, and while adding content under this content type I wanted to provide author, the facility to save this content as draft which he later can edit and publish, ideally, a button with "Save Draft" besides "Publish" button. Is there any drupal module that provides such functionality. I have gone through "[Save Draft](http://drupal.org/project/save_draft)" module, but I don't understands it exact functionality, it is just providing a button with label, what exactly is is doing is not clear to me. Please help me if I am missing something.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You already have the vast majority of this by simply allowing the node to be saved in an unpublished state, then only the author and any admins can view the node. Sure, you could move the published check box to a "Publish" button if you want, but I frankly hope there's no such module, as its to small and specific to warrant the namespace on d.o.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would the main use of this? If a content is kept as unpublished it is similar to saving the draft. It will not be visible to anyone else except the author and admin and any one else you have given permission to view the same. So this in itself is a good option. The save as draft module does the same thing it creates a button to uncheck or check the publish unpublish checkbox.

If you are looking for a workflow kind of feature then workflow module would be a better option. where you can define different workflow status and give different users permission to access the node in each workflow state.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Probably I am missing something very basic thing as in my add content form I don't have unpublished button. There are only two buttons, "Publish" and "Preview", so I thought of this. Can you tell me how can I give author permission to mark new content as "Unpublished".

Comment: when you add a content there is a section called publishing options. which has three options, Published,
Promoted to front page, Sticky at top of lists. You can uncheck the Published to make a post unpublished. As for permissions you should give "View own unpublished content" Hope that helps

Comment: Actually I wanted to give two button at the same time "Save" and "Publish", so that author will decide if he wants to Publish the content or save as draft. Is it possible?

Comment: that is what the save as draft module does. it adds additional button.

Comment: But when I used, that module, and added the content and clicked on save as draft, still the content was in "Published" state in the admin panel.

Comment: I get the correct function. When I use the Save Draft it is shown as not published in the content list. Are you using any other module that handles publishing?

Comment: It is working now. Many thanks for your time. -- Regards